# Virtual machine does not show Graphical user interface

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, virtual-console

I have a VM running ubuntu 16.04 desktop version. I am able to access the vm from my host machine through a terminal, but however i cannot access the desktop version (graphical). The screen appears black. For some reasons i dont want to shut down the VM. is there any way to get it working?

Comment: What command are you using/errors are you getting when trying to shutdown the machine via console?

Comment: I don't want to shut down the VM . sorry for the ambiguity in my question. I just want the console to be visible as earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo service sddm restart` if this doesn't work, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>F7</kbd>